# Screen Capture on Retina MacBook Pro at a Lower Resolution?

Tags: screen-capture, display

I use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to capture screenshots on my MacBook Pro with a Retina display.

I'd like to paste these captures immediately into another app I'm using. The problem I'm encountering is the resolution is so high, I have to first load them into an image editing app and scale them down 50%.

I was wondering if there was some system config to control the scaling of screen captured images automatically to save me the extra step?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/how-can-i-stop-my-retina-display-from-taking-2x-sized-screenshots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this exact issue the other day. Try [RetinaCapture](http://www.retinacapture.com): it's a free app that captures screenshots in both 1x and 2x simultaneously (or, alternatively, just one or the other). And it's a "true" 1x capture: it redraws at 1x rather than taking the 2x version and scaling it down.

It also supports the same types of captures as the built-in Grab.app – full screen, timed screen, selection, or window – and you can save either to the clipboard or a file.

Comment: Looks like it's now U.S. $5 rather than free.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "RetinaCapture" app - www.retinacapture.com/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please see the help center regarding [self-promotion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and make sure you disclose if you are affiliated with a product.