# How to get sharp screenshots from clipboard on a retina MacBook?

Tags: display, preview, screen-capture, copy-paste

I would love to have a way to grab a screenshot to clipboard (via <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>) and then paste it into Gmail on Chrome without it being so fuzzy.

I do NOT want to save the screenshot (and run a folder action or whatever) and I do NOT want to launch a separate app that will save multiple versions of my screenshot.

Is this possible?

[This thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/how-can-i-stop-my-retina-display-from-taking-2x-sized-screenshots) describes 
a promising shell workflow, but when I tried it my results were either extremely blurry or completely garbled.

My current procedure, after copying, is to

1. Open Preview
2. Create a "New from Clipboard"
3. Tools > Adjust Size...
4. Change Resolution from 144 to 72 ppi
5. Copy & Paste

This gives the desired result, but is cumbersome.

I was hoping there was a way to do this through AppleScript, but Preview's dictionary is empty.

Comment: Try the grab tool's dictionary. Might be something there. It is just a simple screenshot tool...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop my retina display from taking 2x sized screenshots?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/how-can-i-stop-my-retina-display-from-taking-2x-sized-screenshots)

Comment: @tubedogg That question focuses on handling screenshots saved to disk. I am looking for a clipboard-only solution.

Comment: @bret7600 Sorry, where is the "grab tool"? I don't see a dictionary from Script Editor.

Comment: There is no clipboard-only solution because you want to make alterations to the image before using it. You may be able to make a workflow that's triggered by you taking a screenshot to file (such as using [RetinaCapture](http://www.retinacapture.com/), having it save to a particular folder, and having a folder action which copies a new image file to the clipboard) but at some point it is going to involve files, which is what the other question is about. If you want to extend that to "...and then copy to clipboard without my interaction," please edit your question.

Comment: @tubedogg Sorry, isn't "I would love to have a way to grab a screenshot to clipboard and then paste it into Gmail" clear enough?

Comment: @bret7600 OK, I see the Grab.app in Utilities, but it doesn't seem to have any dictionary.

Comment: I [commented](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/#comment311802_129428) on the script workflow in the other question with a command that should work.